# SQL Server Query Output for Excel Report

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, sql-server-2014, coldfusion-11

I have a database that has the tables and columns below. There are other columns I need but I'm trying to keep this simple for an answer.

**Stakeholders** (Person's data...name, address, city, state, zip, etc)

- Columns: `Stakeholder_id`, `Full_name`

**Inquiries** (Information about when a stakeholder contacted you)

- Columns: `sh_inquiry_id` (inquiry id), `sh_cr_id` (stakeholder id)

**Followups** (response to an inquiry)

- Columns: `followup_id`, `followup_inquiry_id` (inquiry id)

I'm trying to create a report (final output would be Excel) which would show the data like this:

- Stakeholder (1)

  - Inquiry (1)

    - Followup (1)
  - Inquiry (2)
- Stakeholder (2)

  - Inquiry (1)

    - Followup (1)
  - Inquiry (2)

Some Inquiries don't have followups, stakeholders can have any number of inquiries and inquiries can have any number of followups.

My question is, can this be done through SQL, or do you think I need to format data through my app? Is a report like this better suited to the SQL Server Reporting tool? I'm using SQL server 2014 and ColdFusion 11.

Comment: My approach would be to make the sql simple and use the group attribute of cfoutput to organize your results.

Comment: Yes, it could be done with SQL using outer joins and grouped outputs as Dan mentioned. What is "Best" is relative. What have you tried so far and what were the results?